# Inner constructor in Julia with different name than the struct

Tags: struct, constructor, julia

I saw this construction in rationals.jl, and I am trying to understand it.  I can write

```
struct Bar
    y
    global func(x) = new(x)
end
```

Then if I try:

```
a = Bar()
```

I get an error.  It is like `func` is now an inner constructor.  And I can actually use it by writing:

```
a = func(2)
```

If I remove the keyword `global`, I can't use this inner constructor anymore.  What is going on?  Why is `global` there, and could I use the inner constructor somehow without it (perhaps by qualifying the name)?

How can the inner constructor have a different name than the struct itself?  What, in fact, *is* an inner constructor?

Comment: Have you read the [Bibel](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/constructors/#man-inner-constructor-methods)?

Comment: Yes I read it, but where does it say anything about the exact construction above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL/DR

An inner constructor is a method of the struct type (i.e., `(::Type{Bar})(...)` which has access to `new`.  You can put arbitrary method definitions inside a struct -- there is no technical requirement to only have inner constructors -- but this is only useful in rare cases.

---

### Long version

This is a rare case that the manual doesn't even cover explicitely (and I long didn't know was legal at all).  In my understanding, two rules apply:

1. Inside the struct definition, and only there, you are allowed to use `new`.
2. > If any inner constructor method is defined, no default constructor method is provided: it is presumed that you have supplied yourself with all the inner constructors you need.

However, nothing requires the inner constructor to be a method of the struct type!  Instead you may actually define arbitrary methods.

And then, scoping applies.  With a "regular" inner constructor, what you get is a method for `Type{Bar}`.  This requires no `global`, as the type is present in outer scope.

In your case, without the `global`, `func` is local and so there is no constructor accessible at all outside the struct definition. This makes little sense.  The `global` function definition is something that can be useful in rare cases when you want to prevent direct construction of values of you type, but only allow conversion.  I have seen this kind of pattern:

```
struct Baz
    Base.reinterpret(::Type{Baz}, ...) = new(...)
end
```

This adds a (globally available) method to `reinterpret`, the only entry point to constructing `Baz`es.  Putting it inside the struct is necessary, as at some place you *need* to create the object and thus require access to `new`.

Comment: This is very interesting, thanks!  Out of curiosity: is there a way to access the function defined inside the struct if you don't declare it global?  I tried things like Bar.func, but it doesn't work.  This is actually a useful construction: sometimes you want to have an "unsafe" constructor like for Rational that doesn't do any checks, and you don't want to export this unsafe constructor.

Comment: I think not by any regular means -- this should work like normal scoping. But you could make a method of a global but not exported function.